# apt: list packages with the repositories they are coming from

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb

I've found

```
dpkg-query --showformat="\${Package}\t\${Version}\n" --show \*
```

but it can't show the repo can it? Probably that info is only known to apt. But which apt command to use?

I'd preferably like to have a list like "zypper packages" gives, example:

```
i | SLES11-SP4-Updates      | zypper                              | 1.6.335-29.9                     | x86_64
```

Also I'd preferably like to know which installed debs are not coming from any currently known repository (which zypper would show as "@System").

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-cache policy SLES11-SP4-Updates
```

Comment: "SLES11-SP4-Updates" is the repo in that case. I would like a listing `Repo | Package | Version`, for all packages